# jquery tabs taking long time to load due to Google OAuth2

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, google-oauth

I recently moved to google Oauth2 authorisation for my webpage that has multiple jquery tabs.
On clicking the tab, a Get request is triggered, after shifting to Google OAuth2, the time to load these tabs have increased by atleast 5x times. Previously I used server-side Apache Authorisation. I am assuming the Get request data is getting authorised by google then rendered on page (which might be causing this latency), is there some way to solve this problem.

I tried serially loading each tab as one of the ways,by trying this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433615/jquery-load-multiple-tabs-serially) but that didnt work well. Although I think there could be a better way to solve this.